# FSEvents_connect invalid destination port blocking gulp process

Tags: gulp, ipc, browser-sync, fsevents

Hi there: While building a project, I got this error:

```
2017-04-13 12:05 gulp[64643] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: ERROR: FSEvents_connect() => (ipc/send) invalid destination port (268435459)
```

followed by this at the end of the gulp process [I do not know if they are related]

```
Message:
Command failed: /Users/toddpage/Code/RollKall-Coordinator-Portal/node_modules/node-notifier/vendor/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -title "Gulp notification" -message "Finished Script compilation" -appIcon "/Users/toddpage/Code/RollKall-Coordinator-Portal/node_modules/gulp-notify/assets/gulp.png"

Details:
    killed: false
    code: null
    signal: SIGABRT
    cmd: /Users/toddpage/Code/RollKall-Coordinator-Portal/node_modules/node-notifier/vendor/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -title "Gulp notification" -message "Finished Script compilation" -appIcon "/Users/toddpage/Code/RollKall-Coordinator-Portal/node_modules/gulp-notify/assets/gulp.png"
```

I have since undone any code changes that may have caused this, and rebuilt the project, but I am still getting this error. Any help would be wildly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, this is an iTerm bug related to your session time if you just restart your iTerm it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my computer fixed it for me, logging the current user out and back in might do the trick as well.

Comment: In my case, closing the iTerm tab, and opening a new one, and then running `npm` again fixed it (iTerm2 on Mac)